# Can I reference a class instance with a variable in Python?

Tags: python

I have a list of class instances and I want to check if a particular instance in is in the list using a variable set at run time.

```
class Animal():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

cat = Animal('cat')
dog = Animal('dog')
fish = Animal('fish')

animals = [cat, dog, fish]

assert dog in animals # True

target = 'dog'
assert target in animals # Error
```

Can this be done?

Comment: maybe something like `assert target in map(lambda animal: animal.name, animals)`?

Comment: `target = 'dog'` is currently totally unconnected to the `Animal` instance `dog`. If you implemented `__eq__` appropriately you could do e.g. `Animal(target) in animals`, or you could make a list/set of `.name`s and check in that instead.

Comment: Of *course* you can reference a class instance with a variable. **everything that you can assign to a variable is a class instance in Python**, in fact, it is impossible to do anything else. Your problem is that with `target = "dog"` you are referencing an *instance of `str`*, not an instance of `Animal`.

Comment: Did you mean `target = dog`?

Comment: You can add `def __eq__(self, other): return self.name == other` in your class, but it's hard to guess what exactly you want.

Comment: Currently I have to use `for animal in animals: if animal.name == target:` I'd like to be able to use `if target in animals:`.

Comment: @AndrewH well, then don't assign a `str` object to `target`, because `animals` is a list that only contains `Animal` objects, so it should not be `True` if you check if it contains a `str` object

Comment: @Cyttorak that would be a terrible idea, almost certainly.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I agree, only mentioned because it seemed like that's what the op wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

`dog` is an instance of the Animal class.

You could try loop through each of the classes and get the `.name` and compare like so:

```py
class Animal():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

cat = Animal('cat')
dog = Animal('dog')
fish = Animal('fish')

animals = [cat, dog, fish]

assert dog in animals # True

target = 'dog'

for class_obj in animals:
    print(target == class_obj.name)
```

Comment: Another similar option would be to store the animals in a `dict` by name, rather than a list: `animals = {animal.name: animal for animal in animals}`.